# How to deploy a node.js app for testing

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, mean-stack

I just created a simple web app using the MEAN stack, and I want to host it online somewhere (I'm brand new to the MEAN stack).  I have done this with static pages (using only HTML and CSS) using other sites such as BitBalloon, but since this is my first deploy with the MEAN stack, I really don't know how to get it online.  I'd prefer using a free service for now since I just want to test my app, and share it with friends.  For example, BitBalloon will give you an address like `http://stoker-neutrons-12345.bitballoon.com/`, which is perfect for testing your app, and sharing it with others.  Is there a similar method/hosting site available for apps built on the MEAN stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will probably be closed quickly for being a ["recommendation question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question), which doesn't fit SO's target, but still, here are two recommendations:

- [RedHat OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html) provides a free tier with plenty of functionality.
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)'s "free" package might also work if you're just testing. However, your container will go to "sleep" after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Be prepared, that both options require some effort on getting things rolling (steps are different than simply FTPing some files). But at least Heroku provides some quick start instructions (RedHat probably too, but I haven't checked)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I thought I was doing something wrong when I couldn't deploy successfully to Heroku, but it sounds like deployment is another animal.  Since I don't want to violate any Terms of Service, is there another place (or site) where recommended questions like this should be asked?